# Using CustomUser as author giving problem with database?

Tags: django

I am a little stuck, i am using CustomUser in settings `(AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser')` and i want to use the username as author in comments.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
```

when i run the migrations, it gives me this error

> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.DataError:
>   invalid input syntax for integer: "Alandivar"

Alandivar being my superuser username in devmode,

so how can i make it so when a customer put a comment in (requires login), the username is automatically used as author

regards

customuser form

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = UserChangeForm.Meta.fields
```

customuser model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

customuser view

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Comment: How did you implement the `CustomUser`? Please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: So you are passing the username to the `author` field while creating Comment instance. You should give the id of the user, not the username.

Comment: Try removing all the database entries from CustomUser and then try the migration again.

Comment: removing the entries from database worked the error didnt show anymore, but for some reason author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) give me a number instead of the username. from templates i simply use user.username and it work but how can i get the username in model :/